# How to identify a node that has no subscriber? (ZeroMQ)

Tags: c, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am currently designing a message broker in CZMQ (High-level C binding for ZeroMQ). My broker design is somewhat like the typical star-topology but with additional `REP`-sockets to communicate with the publishers and the subscribers. I also have a `PUB`-socket to notify publishers about subscribers.

When a node connects to the broker it has to do a handshake through this `REP`-socket and that node then gets added to an internal list in the server. My node structure looks like this:

```
struct node {
    int type;
    char *uuid;
    char *path;
    size_t path_len;
    int64_t timestamp;
};
```

The `path` variable is the subscription path that the publisher/subscriber is using, e.g. `/path/to/subscription`.

I keep two different internal lists, one for publishers and one for subscribers. I want to design it so that when a publisher has no subscriber the server will notify that publisher so it can stop sending out messages until another subscriber that subscribes to that publisher.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to figure out if a publisher has no subscribers, for example lets say that a publisher publishes to `/path/to/data`, I then need to find if there are any subscriber that are subscribed to `/path`, `/path/to` or `/path/to/data`.

Each node in this network has a unique ID, the `uuid`. Each publisher has a `SUB`-socket that subscribes to it's own `uuid` so that it can receive updates from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

**Alt.1)**
Create your own explicit subscription-management layer, independent of the standard `PUB/SUB` Scalable Formal Communication Behaviour Archetype Pattern. There you can achieve whatever functionality your design wants to have.

**Alt.2)**
Use the standard `XPUB/XSUB` Archetype, where both subscription and unsubscription messages are enclosed. Yet, these are weak-type signalling and one may simply miss or never 've been intended to receive a such message, so your handling strategy must become robust enough not to get into troubles, if weak-signalling messages are not presented.

> **`ZMQ_XPUB`**
>
> Same as `ZMQ_PUB` except that you can **receive** subscriptions from the peers in form of incoming messages. Subscription message is a byte **`1`** (for subscriptions) or byte **`0`** (for unsubscriptions) followed by the subscription body. Messages without a sub/unsub prefix are also received, but have no effect on subscription status.
>
> **`ZMQ_XSUB`**
>
> Same as `ZMQ_SUB` except that you subscribe by **sending** subscription messages to the socket. Subscription message is a byte **`1`** (for subscriptions) or byte **`0`** (for unsubscriptions) followed by the subscription body. Messages without a sub/unsub prefix may also be sent, but have no effect on subscription status.

Last but not least, one need not worry about no `SUB`-s being present, as the Context()-instances' internal data-pumps' management is well-aware about connections' state and not having troubles on the empty list of `SUB`-s. If using a `.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE, 1 )` method, the locally allocated resources for the `SUB`-s' Queue storage-capacity management will keep just the one, most recent message in the local Queue-head-end storage for each <sub>*almost*</sub>"live"-`SUB`.

Thats cute, isn't it?

Comment: I'm leaning for option 2 but I don't really understand the subscription messages for subscribing/unsubscribing. Is this something that ZeroMQ is handling under the hood or do I have to manually send such requests?

Comment: Yes, explicit sending is the way forward to harness the **`XPUB/XSUB`** archetype for the task you have set. Read about multipart message composition on sending side and decomposition on receive side and you will like it. Testing for the first part content size ( 1B ) and value `{0|1}` is quite a cheap cost to benefit from all this smart and ready-to-reuse mechanisation, isnt't it?

Comment: I read a bit about multipart message and I understand the concept now. I did a minimal example in CZMQ, a server that uses `zproxy` with `XSUB` and `XPUB` sockets and a capture socket so that I can see what comes through the server, and a very simple client that sends on a `PUB` socket and receives on a `SUB` socket and it all worker nicely if I started the `SUB` socket before I sent the message on the `PUB` socket, did not work if I started the `PUB` socket first and sent the message. Is this because of the slow-joiner syndrome and if so is there a nice and clean way to solve it?

Comment: I figured it out why this happened and solved it by using a rep-req synchronization handshake on the `PUB` socket before starting sending out data. Thanks for all the help!